# Dynamically Create DB Connection String for Entity in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an entity in MVC 4 project and the connection string is placed in the web.config by the entity creation wizard.

I need to change this and assign the password to the connection string (which is stored outside the web.config) at run time.

1. How can I combine values outside the web.config with a string stored inside the web.config?
2. Or can I move the entity connection completely outside the web.config?

**This is the existing entity connection string:**

```
add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.NewUsers.csdl|res://*/Models.NewUsers.ssdl|res://*/Models.NewUsers.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=mydb;initial catalog=MyDatabase;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=Mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 3):

For 2, you can always pass a new connectionString (not from `web.config`) directly to the context when you create it:

```
string newCS = "add name=...";
var context = new MyEntities(newCS);
```

For 1, [use EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx) to parse an existing CS or build a new one.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might be to use something based on:

```
string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PerinatalDataEntities"].
    ConnectionString;
con = con.replace("user id=sa", "user id=MyUser").
    Replace("password=Mypassword","password=MyNewpassword")
```

I believe there is also a connection builder but I've never used it.

Comment: Using the EntityConnectionStringBuilder is a much better approach.